# Can there be two parameters in equation of family of circles passing through the points of intersection of a line and a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

I always find it written as:
S + kL = 0,  (where k is the parameter).

But while playing in Desmos I found out the it can also be written as L + kS =0
or more generally , mS + kL = 0. (where both m and k are parameters).
Am I right? If I am then why don't I find these forms anywhere?

Comment: because all three are same

Comment: If $L+kS=0$, then $(1/k)L+S=0$ if $k\ne 0$. The third alternative is another way to express a line with the other forms being recoverable by setting $m=1$ and choosing the appropriate $k$. Given two points on a circle, construct the perpendicular bisector to the segment joining them. Set a radius of a circle on this bisector with radius passing through either point, and you get a qualifying circle.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you